# Understanding why $\log_2 (3) > 0$.

Tags: proof-explanation, logarithms

I see it often taken for granted that because $3 > 2$, $\log_2 (3) > 0$ (or, in fact, $\log_2 (3) > 1$.

I'm not sure I understand why. It's certainly the case that $2^{\log_2 (3)} = 3$, by definition. Further, $2^1 = 1$. As the function $f(x) = 2^x$ is monotonically increasing, I should be able to deduce that $\log_2 (3) > 1$.

Is it as simple as that? I didn't think it was necessary to consider the case that $\log_2 (3)$ is negative, in which case I get some number less than $\frac{1}{2}$, which is surely absurd.

Comment: $2^1=2$, and yes, it is that simple. To get a $3$, the exponent must be bigger than $1$ since the exponent of $1$ only gets you up to $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any increasing function $f(x)$ , if $x_1,x_2$ lie in interval of increase then

$$x_1>x_2\iff f(x_1)>f(x_2)$$

( because that's how an increasing function is defined)

Since you already told that $2^x$ is monotonically increasing, therefore

$$3>1\iff \log_23>\log_21=0$$